# Using ajax for form submission with multiple forms generated by php on page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook-like

I have a page with multiple forms that do the same thing, acting as a `like` button for each post in the page, and right next to it the number of likes inside a div named "likes".$id, so I can identify where to write the likes count after the ajax call. I was trying to use jQuery ajax function, but I couldn't set what div to write the results of the function.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST', 
  url: 'likepost.php', 
  data:$('#like').serialize(), 
  success: function(response) {
    $('#like').find('#likediv').html(response);
  }
});
```

And how would I access the data on likepost.php? I am terrible with javascript, so I hope someone could help me and explain how the jQuery function really works, because I've been copying and pasting it without really knowing what I was doing.

Would this work?

```
    $(function () {

    $("#likebutton").click(function () {

            var id = $('input[name=id]'); // this is me trying to get a form value

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "likepost.php",
           data: $("#like"+id).serialize(), // the form is called like+id e.g. like12
           success: function(data){

                 $("#likes"+id).html(data); // write results to e.g. <div id='likes12'>

               }
         });            
    });
});
```

I put this in the code but when the button is clicked, the usual post refreshing page is done. Why is that?

Comment: @GregPettit, Smart tips!

Comment: Would be useful if you show the HTML code of at least one DIV named ` "likes".$id`

Comment: Sorry about that, I know nothing about javascript, that said, I know nothing about the convention of how to indent it. This post has an id of 143 and has 2 likes: <div id='likes143'>2</div>

Comment: Let me reformulate my question: how can I access a value passed by the form inside the ajax function? That way I would concatenate "likes"+id and set what I want (the div to write).

Answer (score 0):

Making a mini-form, serializing it, and POSTing it seems like a lot of heavy lifting when all you really want to do is send the ID to the likepost.php script.

Why not just retrieve the ID and post it to the script?

Answer (score 0):

First let's break down your function:Type is the type of the request we're making, you specified POST here. This means in your PHP file you'll access the data we're sending using $_POST. Next up is URL which is just the url of where you're sending the data, your php file in this case.

After that is data, that is the data we're sending to the url (likepost.php). You're serializing whatever has a ID of "like" and sending it to the php file. Finally success is a function to run once the request is successful, we get a response back from the PHP and use it in the function to output the response.

As for the multiple forms I'd recommend doing something like: 
http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-checkbox-array-in-form-handling-multiple-checkbox-values-in-an-array.html

Here's documentation on the stuff we talked about, if you're every confused about jquery just break it down and search each part.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
function submitform(id) {
    var jqxhr = $.post('./likepost.php',$("#"+id).serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#"+id).find('#likediv').html(data);
    }, "json")
    return false;
}
```

in form:

```
<form method="post" id="likeForm" onsubmit="return submitform(this.id);">
    <input..... />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

in likepost.php add first line:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != "XMLHttpRequest") {
    header("location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit();
}
```

you can see more : `http://api.jquery.com/serialize/`
working for me.